# How to make header content responsive (stack header image on top of content div when small screen)

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image (it's the header of my page). On top of this background image, I placed an opaque layer with some text inside. My problem is the way this text behaves when I adjust the screen size to a smaller screen:

My goal is to have the image div (maincontainer) stack on top of the content-div, so that there are two separate rows, BUT only from a certain (small) screen size.

At the moment, the two containers are layered on top of each other.

Can anyone give me a hint how to fix this? What property could I use (in my media query) other than "display: block"? Here is the code I have so far (it's probably terrible since I am quite new to this):

(FYI: I have no access to the head portion of the site.)

```css
<style type="text/css">.maincontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("xyz.jpg");
}

.headercontent {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.opacitycontainer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 77, .6);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: inherit;
  bottom: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: 35%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .opacitycontainer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .opacitycontainer {
    width: 35%;
  }
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(0, 88, 156);
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="maincontainer">
  <div class="opacitycontainer">
    <div class="headercontent">
      <div style="text-align: right;">Admission</div>

      <h2>Some text!</h2>

      <div class="boutonbc"><a href="link;" target="_blank">Apply now!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
  .background-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
  }
  .text-overlay-container {
    width: 78%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 11%;
    text-align: center;
  }
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .text-overlay-container {
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<div class="maincontainer">
  <div class="opacitycontainer">
    <div class="headercontent">
      <div style="text-align: right;">Admission</div>

      <h2>Some text!</h2>

      <div class="boutonbc"><a href="link;" target="_blank">Apply now!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```